# Is it okay to provide an answer to a question in an unrelated programming language?

Tags: discussion, answers, code-languages

This question is related to the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53014407/algorithm-find-two-positive-integers-whose-difference-is-minimized-and-whose-pr/53014561#53014561).

OP was posing a question and looking for a solution in [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) (see the tags). The question ended up being answered (and the answer was accepted), but in a programming language that is not [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba).

Before the answer was accepted, I flagged the answer as "not an answer", because I didn't think it would help OP. Fortunately for him, it appears he was able to translate the pseudo code just fine. My flag was eventually declined.

But will this kind of answer on a post tagged for [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) & [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) help future users? It seems to me that it goes against the ideology of building a programmer's encyclopedia here on Stack Overflow. Is the community okay with people answering questions in other programming languages or pseudo code?

Comment: Yes. Whether or not such an answer is *useful*, however, is a different topic entirely.

Comment: If linked duplicate is not enough please edit to clarify why this post is different from existing discussions https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=answer+different+language (I agree that SO search is not top-of-the-line but it may bring some existing posts).

Answer (score 4):

Pseudocode is not a programming language, for starters.

If nothing else, the [answer provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53014561/1079354) gave the OP a breadcrumb on how to solve the problem.

This is fine; even if the answer isn't something you can take straight from Stack Overflow and paste it into something to make work, getting the basics of what you need to do to solve this is more than sufficient to make for a passable answer.

It'd be a *different* story if the OP asked about pointer arithmetic and were given an answer in Prolog.

Comment: `even if the answer isn't something you can take straight from Stack Overflow and paste it into something to make work` — I'd argue that this is a _good_ thing, since it forces the OP to think about what they're doing, instead of blindly pasting, and having no idea what to do when they change a variable name.